# IIS Express Does Not Recognize Running VS2022 as Admin

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I had a computer with VS2019 Community installed. I got a new computer, copied my documents over, and installed VS2022 Community. I am launching VS as admin. In the upper-right corner of VS it says "Admin". Also, when launching VS I get the User Account Control prompt associated with launching as an admin. Yet when I build my solution and launch IIS Express, I get a message "...You do not have permission to access the IIS configuration file. Opening and creating web sites on IIS requires running Visual Studio under an Administrator account". Does anyone know what else to do or have a suggestion of what else to look at? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the message is a red herring. I incorrectly assumed that IIS Express was installed with VS. The solution was to install IIS Express.